# How to Enable/Disable Particular Assertion in all Test Case using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have suite to run the regression Test Case in Soap UI. It has a Assertion `Capture Response` which measures the time of each request. This is needed on demand.

If metrics needed then I need to Enable the Capture Response Time assertion and if it is not needed then I don't need the capture response time.

I have written the below code to check that whether it is disabled or not. If it is disabled then OK else i need to disable it.

The following code returns

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'disabled' on null object.

Can any one help on this?

```
def project = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject().getWorkspace().getProjectByName("Regression");
//Loop through each Test Suite in the project
    for(suite in project.getTestSuiteList()) 
    {
        //log.info(suite.name)
            //Loop through each Test Case
        if(suite.name == "ReusableComponent")
        {
            for(tcase in suite.getTestCaseList()) 
            {               
                  log.info(tcase.name)
                  for(tstep in tcase.getTestStepList())
                  {
                    stepName = tstep.name
                    suiteName=suite.name
                    caseName=tcase.name
                    def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["$suiteName"].testCases["$caseName"].getTestStepByName("$stepName")
                    log.info(testStep.getAssertionByName("CaptureResponseTime").disabled)
                  }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ChanGan, have you got chance to try the solution to see if that helps?

Comment: Tried and it is working fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below statement is causing `NullPointerException`:

```
log.info(testStep.getAssertionByName("CaptureResponseTime").disabled)
```

In order to avoid **NPE**, then change it to:

```
log.info(testStep.getAssertionByName("CaptureResponseTime").isDisabled)
```

If you need to **disable the assertion**, then use below statement:

```
testStep.getAssertionByName("CaptureResponseTime")?.disabled = true
```

Another input:

In order to get the `project`, do not use `workspace`.

Instead use:

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
```